# s3 throughput with very small objects

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to reorganize ~150 million very small objects in S3. The largest is 13 MB. ~99.9% of them are less than 200 KB. ~98% of them are less than 2 KB. I need to process at least 100 keys a second for the timing to become vaguely reasonable.

I've been attempting to download and process them concurrently with an app using the Java SDK from an m4.xlarge. I use fifty threads, each of which 1) gets a key from RabbitMQ, 2) downloads the file from S3, 3) decompresses the file, 4) splits it into messages, and 5) republishes the split messages into RabbitMQ to be reorganized.

As it is, the app struggles to maintain 20 keys per second (as measured by the inbound queue for step 1). It seems very likely that it's step 2 -- S3 -- which is hampering the flow; the logic and other IO seem negligible. That would suggest that the Java SDK for S3 and S3 are only allowing around 40 KB per second downloads, which is, of course, ridiculous.

I know that a large number of small objects is far from ideal -- that's a big part of why I'm trying to reorganize them -- and that I can ask AWS to optimize the transfer (which I'm doing), but beyond that and simply increasing the concurrency (which seems sufficient already), are there steps I can take to increase the throughput?

Comment: Try to increase the concurrency, there is a lot of overhead/wait for grabbing something out of s3. Assuming that the processing is not very CPU intensive, you might be able to drastically increase the number of threads as much of the time is waiting for network calls to resolve.

Comment: I've personally pushed buckets beyond 500 req/second and 1 Gbit/second with fewer than 50 threads (though I don't do Java), so I'm inclined to think the problem is somewhere else.  It sounds like you need some millisecond-level benchmarking peppered into your code to find it.  Of course, verify that the bucket and the instance are in the same region.  Beyond that, I see no obvious answer at this point.  There's no fundamental problem with millions of objects, unless they aren't sensible units, so it also is unclear what exactly you are solving.